# import statement error for Micronaut - Gradle project in Eclipse JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, micronaut, javax.inject

I have created a simple micronaut project using mn cli and followed the steps to generate eclipse project (using `gradlew eclipse` )

Everything looks fine however when I create any service and annotate with `@Singleton` annotation, Eclipse gives the error for following import statement,
`import javax.inject.Singleton`

[image]

The error is `The import javax.inject.Singleton cannot be resolved`

However if I use the wildcard import like,

[image]

No issues reported by Eclipse.

Please note that despite Eclipse showing the error, the project builds and runs perfectly fine from command line using `gradlew run`

However it's a hinderance in case if I want to debug the code.

It must be something to do with Eclipse JDT compiler, but I can't figure out.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: If you hover the mouse over `@Singleton` in the wildcard case what does the pop-up say the full type is? If you press F3 (Open Declaration) with `@Singleton` selected what does it open?

Comment: It is opening public @interface Singleton {} inside javax.inject-1.jar

Comment: Surprisingly javax.inject.Inject works perfectly fine, which is a sibling interface of Singleton